# Error using sp_send_dbmail with a @query parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-mail

This has been asked many times, and every time I've seen, the solution is to add the `@execute_query_database` parameter. Well, as you can see, I have that parameter and this code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'GMail',
@recipients = 'brady@bradykelly.net',
@subject = 'Snappy Referrals', -- add date
@body = 'Hello, DB mail!',
@execute_query_database = 'SeniorExecs',
@query = N'SELECT * from Language'
```

Still gives the error below as long as the `@query` parameter is present. When I comment out that one line, the proc call works and the mail is sent.

```
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
```

When I examine the DB Mail logs, in the `Sql Server` section, everytime I try and execute the proc, an entry like this gets added:

> Unknown,Disallowing page allocations for database 'WideWorldImporters'
>   due to insufficient memory in the resource pool 'default'.

At this point, the only thing to say about database `WideWorldImporters` is that it is on the same SQL server. I encountered it nowhere setting up a mail profile and user account.

Comment: How many rows does the query return? What do your wait stats look like?

Comment: What db is the `Language` table in?  I suspect your query is using a different database than where that table is located.  Put a `USE [dbname] GO` above your call to `sp_send_dbmail` and try it again.

Comment: I believe the point was that `@execute_query_database` determines the database where the query is executed. Just to clarify. Still entirely true that `sp_send_dbmail` may be running in the `WideWorldImporters` context, and thus a memory allocation issue within `sp_send_dbmail` would be likely to report the problem within that context.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener in that case you normally get an error like `Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server Server name, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.language'.`

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Agreed, but my question wasn't meant to be an answer, rather I was asking for more information.  RDFozz's comment gets to the underlying logic regarding it a bit better though.

Comment: Well, even with a `using` statement in the query, nothing changes and the memory thing is still with `WideWorldImporters`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try using a fully qualified (SeniorExecs.dbo.Language) for your @query parameter.  Also, if possible as a test, you 'might' try taking WideWorldImporters offline temporarily - it might help in determining WHY this database is even in the mix (ex: unable to connect to default database or other messages)

Comment: @ScottHodgin, Yes, I did try that, as an alternative to the `@execute_query_database` param, and in addition to it.

Answer (score 1):

Going an entirely different direction than what I was thinking of in the comments, if you're running this from within a job, [this blog post](http://harshbiplus.blogspot.in/2015/01/failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library.html) suggests adding the SQL Agent account to the `sysadmin` fixed server role.

I doubt you have to go that far to fix this, and I suspect you only really need to grant the SQL Agent user (or whatever user owns the job in question) a [minimum set of permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql#permissions), which are *execute* permissions on the `sp_send_dbmail` procedure, ensuring it's a member of the `DatabaseMailUser` database role in the `msdb` database, and finally, making sure it can access the data being returned by the query you're passing to the `sp_send_dbmail` routine itself.